# Cylindrical coordinate derivative of a vector field.

Tags: derivatives, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, tensors

Considering the following identity transformation in cylindrical coordinate:

$$\mathbf{v}(R,\theta,z)=R\;\mathbf{e}_{R}+\theta\;\mathbf{e}_{\theta}+z\;\mathbf{e}_{z} $$

Taking its derivative according to the formula for the derivative of a vector field in cylindrical coordinates:

[image]

I expect to obtain the identity but the formula above gives also some non-diagonal terms.
Could you explain me why or give me a good reference?

Comment: That vector field is not the identity. The term $Re_r+ze_z$ alone is the identity.

Comment: Why? How can you remap a point in itself without knowing its theta?

Comment: The $\theta$ information is already encoded in $e_r$. For a simpler case, consider the plane polar coordinates $x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta$. Try to convince yourself that $$\vec r=xe_x+ye_y=re_r.$$ When this is clear, add the $z$ coordinate.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html This picture might be useful.